# cannot find "iAd" framework in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ipad, uikit

I want to add the iAd framework. But cannot find. I am folowing the stpes;

In the project navigator, select your project
Select your target
Select the 'Build Phases' tab
Open 'Link Binaries With Libraries' expander
Click the '+' button

But cannot see the iAd framework..

Just as a hint, I see "Current MAC OS" as the title for the Frameworks list...

I have the latest Xcode 4 and iOS 4 SDK...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your base SDK set to Mac OS instead of iOS?
[image]

Comment: Perfetto..That was the issue...But still wondering why it suddenly changed when I updated XCode/IOS version...Anyways Great answer...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you chosen a Cocoa project by accident. You need to create a Cocoa Touch project.

[Apple iAd Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/iAd_ReferenceCollection/_index.html)

Comment: Actually this is an exisitng live iPhone app, which I am trying to open in my updated XCode 4/IOS 4...So I am hoping it should be the same Cocoa Touch project, as before..

Answer (score 0):

Joe's answer was correct. I recently resumed development on an Xcode 3 project and after **upgrading** to XCode 4 and working on that project I was receiving the "iAd/iAd.h was not found" error when trying to build the project and deploy to my test device specifically. I went to the Base SDK and found it was selecting some random SDK. I updated it to "Latest" and it began to work in all test scenarios.

Comment: Yes..seems to be an upgrade bug!

Answer (score 0):

This was infuriating because the iAd Framework simply wasn't where it was supposed to be (i.e. with the other frameworks).  I already had the latest Base SDK selected.  So, if JoePasq's answer didn't work, you should try doing what I did, and uninstall, then reinstall Xcode.  It will reinstall with all the frameworks.

One way you can tell if you need to do this is if Apple's iAd suite tutorials are also missing the iAd framework.